# On which thread do Async Callbacks run?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

I'm making several `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse` calls, and in the callback method of the `BeginGetResponse`, I'm invoking an EventHandler.  In the EventHandler, there is logic to test if the download was successful.  If not, it tries to redownload the Html.  I'm noticing lots of threads being generated especially when there are errors. So, on which thread do the Async Callbacks run?

Is there anyway I can invoke the EventHandler on the original thread?  If that is not posible, can I invoke it on the UI thread?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Callbacks are made on a threadpool thread.  There is no mechanism in .NET to make code run on a specific thread.  That is very hard to come by, you can't just interrupt a thread while it is busy and make it run some code.  That causes horrible re-entrancy problems that a lock cannot solve.

A thread must be in an idle state, not actively mutating the state of the program.  There's one kind of thread that behaves that way, the UI thread in a Winforms or WPF app.  That's also the thread that has to deal with objects that are fundamentally thread-unsafe, anything related to the UI.  This is not a coincidence.

Both class libraries make it possible to marshal a call from a worker thread to the UI thread, specifically to help getting the UI updated in a thread-safe way.  In Winforms you use Control.Begin/Invoke(), in WPF you use Dispatcher.Begin/Invoke().  BackgroundWorker is a handy class to get this done without explicitly managing the marshaling.  But isn't suitable for I/O completion callbacks.

Comment: Ok, so the Callbacks are made on a thread in the threadpool.  So, if on a threadpool thread I invoke an EventHandler, which thread will it run on?

Comment: EventHandlers are just code - when you call one, the handlers subscribing to the event are run on the calling thread; there's no transition, no magic.

Comment: Thank you!  One last dumb question.  If I call Invoke on the EventHandler, will it run on the UI thread?

Comment: Invoke() runs on the same thread, BeginInvoke() runs on a tp thread.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "on the original thread"? Which original thread? You can marshal to the UI thread using `Control.BeginInvoke` or `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. You can't marshal to an arbitrary thread - it has to have *something* like a message pump waiting for work.

As for which thread `HttpWebRequest` async callbacks are executed on - I would expect either a general thread pool worker thread, or possibly an IO completion port thread.

Comment: "on the original thread" being the thread from where the `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse` is called. So, for example, if the UI spawns a thread A and A calls `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse` (which as you said, puts a new thread in the thread pool.  We'll call it thread B) and then the EventHandler is invoked, I want it to run on thread A or the UI thread.  But from what I've been observing it runs on thread B.  Then, if there is an error, thread B calls `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse` which then creates thread C and so on...  Hope that helps

Comment: @joe_coolish: Why would it run on thread A, and why would you care? What would you expect to happen if thread A is still executing some other code? I'm not at all sure what you mean by BeginGetResponse "putting a new thread in the thread pool" though... or why thread B is calling BeginGetResponse again... is that in your own code? The thread pool will reuse threads when possible of course.

Comment: The reason I care is because I'm getting OOMEs because the thread pool is too big. My code (which is where the real problem lies I'm sure) has 2 methods. 1 accepts a URL and an EventHandler Callback.  It creates the HttpWebRequest object and calls the BeginGetResponse.  Method 2 is the AsyncCallback and if the call errors out it makes a call to method 1 passing the URL and the EventHandler. The problem is that every call from method 2 to 1 generates a new thread and keeps the original thread active so if I start downloading 6 things and each errors out 6 times I now have 36 threads in the pool

Comment: If my design/logic is the problem, my end goal is download HTML from a URL and when it's done, call an event handle.  The downloader needs to have the ability to retry the download X number of times, where X is a constant int.  I also wanted to thank you for your help, and apologize for any errors on my part.  If anything, you can get a good laugh from it :)

Comment: @joe_coolish: How many threads do you *actually* have in the thread pool by the time it goes wrong? The thread pool really should be reusing the threads when it can - I doubt that it's actually spiralling out of control... unless you're in the situation where it's returning an error *really quickly* and you're *always* retrying (i.e. if your counting isn't working). How much memory does your machine have? While threads are *somewhat* expensive, you'd need a lot of them before you ran out of memory on most machines.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Begin/End Async pattern, be aware that it's possible for many kinds of tasks to complete on the thread they were called from.  When you call BeginXXX, it returns a boolean that signifies if the task was completed on the calling thread or not.

The basic answer is, it could be any thread.

Comment: Thank you, I am beginning to find that this is infact the case.  I just now need to get my logic straightened out and I'll be good!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPF you can use the Dispatcher to invoke your logic on the UI thread.

Otherwise, (if not in WPF) you could use a SyncrhronizationContext to accomplish the same thing.