# Which thread does the callback run on?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I've written a small application that calls an Asynchronous method using `BeginInvoke`.

```
// Asynchronous delegate
Func<int, MailItemResult> method = SendMail;

// Select some records from the database to populate col

while (i < col.Count)
{
    method.BeginInvoke(i, SendMailCompleted, method);
    i++;
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

This is in the `Main()` method of a Console Application.  `MailItemResult` is defined as:

```
class MailItemResult
{
    public int CollectionIndex { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

Nice and simple.  And the callback method is defined as follows:

```
static void SendMailCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var target = (Func<int, MailItemResult>)result.AsyncState;
    MailItemResult mir = target.EndInvoke(result);
    if (mir.Success)
    {
        // Update the record in the database
    }
}
```

This application runs for the first 100ish threads and then throws up a deadlock in the database.  Now, I understand deadlocks, but what I'm failing to understand in this small application is in which thread is the callback method (`SendMailCompleted`) being called?  Is this called from the main application thread?  Or is it using the same thread, from the thread pool, that the `BeginInvoke`method was using?

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5531098/210709

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> **Executing a Callback Method When an Asynchronous Call Completes**
>
> [...] The callback method is executed on a ThreadPool thread.